# multiple div draggable misplaced after save in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I save the good  position of div after draggable in my database. But when I want to display divs i have space :

```
 <div id="content">
<div id=table_1 class="ui-widget-content"  style= "border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50%; top:0px; left:0px">vfvv </div>
<div id=table_2 class="ui-widget-content" style= "width: 50px; height: 30px; padding: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;top:0px; left:0px"> </div></div>
```

and my Jquery Code :

```
<script>
        $(function() {
          var map = new Object();   
            //pour chaque div possedant lattribut class
            $( 'div[class]').each(function(index){}).draggable( 
                {   
                    //l'evenement stop correspond fin du drag
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        var position = $(this).position();
                        var $newPosX = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
                        var $newPosY = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
                        map[this.id] = ui.offset;       
                }, 
                    // permet de delimiter la zone 
                    containment: "#content"}).click(function() {
                    alert('nouria mais rose');
            });

            $("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
                var allPosition='';
                for (var m in map){
                allPosition+= m +'-' + map[m].top + '-' + map[m].left+'/';
                }
                 $('input[name=positionTables]').val(allPosition);  
            });

        });


        </script>
```

The probleme is on the successive div. The seconde div always have space but not the first.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what the question is, can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution : 
I use positions'properties at absolute

```
<div id=table_1 class="ui-widget-content"  style= position: absolute;....</div>
```